# Call pyplot from a function to draw multiple lines on the same plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, visualization

When I want to drow multiple lines on the same plot, I can just call `pyplot.plot(x,y)` as many times as I want and then show the plot with `pyplot.show()`. However, when I define a function to plot, and I call that function multiple times, instead of having multiple lines on the same plot, I get multiple plots. For example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotsub(x, y):
    plt.plot(x, y)
    plt.show()

x = np.arange(0,10,1);
y = x*x   
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.plot(x*10,y)
plt.show()

plotsub(x,y)
plotsub(x*10,y)
```

The output of the above code is like this: [image]

However, I would like the two calls to `plotsub` to act just as the way calling `plt.plot` multiple times acts.

Basically, I am trying to obtain a handle for pyplot to send it to a function as an argument, which I cannot find how to do.

Answer (score 2):

It's because you have `plt.show()` inside your `plotsub` function. So each time you call `plotsub`, matplotlib shows the plot, as expected.

If you only want to show the plot after all your calls to `plotsub`, you could move that outside the function:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotsub(x, y):
    plt.plot(x, y)

x = np.arange(0,10,1);
y = x*x   

plotsub(x,y)
plotsub(x*10,y)
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, you could leave it inside the function, but make it optional, so you only show in the last call to `plotsub`. Something like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotsub(x, y, show=False):
    plt.plot(x, y)
    if show:
        plt.show()

x = np.arange(0,10,1);
y = x*x   

plotsub(x, y)
plotsub(x*10, y, show=True)
```

Finally, to get a reference to the line that you plot in the function, you can `return` that from the function, like so:

```
def plotsub(x, y, show=False):
    line, = plt.plot(x, y)
    if show:
        plt.show()
    return line

l1 = plotsub(x, y)
```

Comment: great, thanks!
In general though, is there a way to get a reference to the plot so that I can use it later in other parts of the code?

Comment: yes, you can return that value from your function. See edit above.

Comment: Very nice idea returning the line object!